# Is it best practice to use * {box-sizing: border-box} in 2016 HTML websites?

Tags: html, css

Just like the titles is saying, is it best practice to use `{box-sizing: border-box}` in 2016 HTML websites? And if yes, how do I implement it to use on all browsers (Mozilla, Chrome, Safari...)? I saw this:

[image: Pic]

on http://www.html5xcss3.com/2013/07/10-basic-tips-to-design-a-responsive-website.html

Which made me think about that ;)

Comment: Ironically, the article is behind the times - [vendor prefixes aren't required](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing).

Comment: No, there is no best practice, use it when you need it.

Comment: No. It will unexpectedly scale-down images with borders and `width` or `height` HTML attributes. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hcxo4t2p/1/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personally, I'd say no -- blanket solutions using the universal selector (`*`) are almost never a good idea. Doing something like `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` applies that style to *every single element on the page.* I've seen use of `*` styles have unwanted effects on certain types of elements, like form inputs and buttons. Sometimes the unwanted side-effects are different in different browsers.

By the time side effects crop up in a large enough project, switching to a more conservative approach may require extensive CSS edits and browser testing. For that reason, I favor going with something like [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) or [Eric Meyer's reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) + [Formalize](http://formalize.me/).

Years of wrestling with browser incompatibilities and quirks, sometimes creating my own self-imposed CSS hells along the way, have caused me to mostly favor constrained solutions. Less chance of unpleasant surprises that way.